# How to crop gtk pixbufs

Tags: python, gtk, svg

I've got a gtk - pixbuf out of an svg and want to crop this to a specific size at specific coordinates.

Anyone has an easy possible solution for that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved it in a different way:

simply created a subpixbuf with the coodinates:

`cropped_buffer=pixbuf.subpixbuf(x,y,width,height)`

Answer (score 0):

svg has a [viewbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute. You could use that one.